# How to send message to your follower in twitter using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter, messaging

I have iPhone application in which i used xAuth and i can tweet well but i want to send message to my follower and i don't know how to send message to particular follower.
Please give your ideas to do this stuff.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean a reply or a direct message?

Comment: i mean user can send private message to any follower of his/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE  MGtwitterEngine to send message to particular follower.